# remove xticks within groupplot

Tags: pgfplots, groupplots

Is there a way to get rid of the xticks between the first and
second, and the second and third plots in the groupplot below?  Getting rid of the xticks on the inside of each plot (e.g. the ticks extending from 0 upwards) would do.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotstableread{
wk  1   2   3
0   2   3   4
1   5   6   7
2   0   0   0
3   5   6   7
}\data
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfplotsset{group/vertical sep={0cm},
    group/x descriptions at=edge bottom,
  }
  \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=1 by 3},
                    height=5cm,
                    width=8cm,
                    ybar stacked,
                    xtick=data,
                    ymin=0,
                    xticklabels from table={\data}{wk},
                    tick align=outside
                    ]
    \nextgroupplot
      \addplot [fill=black!60] table [y=1, x expr=\coordindex] {\data};    
      \addplot [fill=black!20] table [y=2, x expr=\coordindex] {\data};
      \addplot [fill=black!40] table [y=3, x expr=\coordindex] {\data};
    \nextgroupplot
      \addplot [fill=black!60] table [y=1, x expr=\coordindex] {\data};    
      \addplot [fill=black!20] table [y=2, x expr=\coordindex] {\data};
      \addplot [fill=black!40] table [y=3, x expr=\coordindex] {\data};
    \nextgroupplot
      \addplot [fill=black!60] table [y=1, x expr=\coordindex] {\data};    
      \addplot [fill=black!20] table [y=2, x expr=\coordindex] {\data};
      \addplot [fill=black!40] table [y=3, x expr=\coordindex] {\data};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are searching for something like this?

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
    \pgfplotstableread{
        wk  1   2   3
        0   2   3   4
        1   5   6   7
        2   0   0   0
        3   5   6   7
    }\data
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[
        group style={
            group size=1 by 3,
            vertical sep={0cm},
            x descriptions at=edge bottom,
        },
        height=5cm,
        width=8cm,
        ybar stacked,
        xtick=data,
        ymin=0,
        xticklabels from table={\data}{wk},
        tick align=outside,
        table/x expr=\coordindex,
    ]
    \nextgroupplot[
        xtick pos=upper,
    ]
        \addplot [fill=black!60] table [y=1] {\data};
        \addplot [fill=black!20] table [y=2] {\data};
        \addplot [fill=black!40] table [y=3] {\data};

    \nextgroupplot[
        xtick style={
            /pgfplots/major tick length=0pt,
        },
    ]
        \addplot [fill=black!60] table [y=1] {\data};
        \addplot [fill=black!20] table [y=2] {\data};
        \addplot [fill=black!40] table [y=3] {\data};

    \nextgroupplot[
        xtick pos=lower,
    ]
        \addplot [fill=black!60] table [y=1] {\data};
        \addplot [fill=black!20] table [y=2] {\data};
        \addplot [fill=black!40] table [y=3] {\data};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]